# How can I build multiple projects as multiple Webassembly wasm files and share them?

Tags: opencv, webassembly

I tried to follow this:
https://www.codepool.biz/webassembly-standalone-dynamic-linking-wasm.html

To build multiple C++ projects as modules in Wasm and reference them (or load them) separately, not as one big Wasm file like in the link.

I'm working on project that uses OpenCV to achive some work, is there a way to compile it as separate Wasm file that I can share between multiple of my modules (each module reference the OpenCV and use its functionality).